# Kotlin how to move a file to a other directory?

Tags: kotlin

Let's assume that I have the following file hierarchy:

- C:\Users\sanpleuser\Downloads > test.txt
- C:\Users\sampleuser\Documents

What I want to achieve is to move the test.txt file from downloads to documents.

Can someone help me out with that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to implement the copyTo method. But I think that is the wrong method because I cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 19):

Kotlin provides an extension function to Java's `File`: `File.copyTo(target: File)`, but unfortunately no `File.moveTo(target: File)`. If you only use small files, you can just use the copy function

You can do this pretty straightforward with the following code:

```
File("C:/Users/sampleuser/Downloads/test.txt").let { sourceFile ->
    sourceFile.copyTo(File("C:/Users/sampleuser/Documents/test.txt"))
    sourceFile.delete()
}
```

Or, if you need it to be *moved*, we can use Java's `nio` package

```
val sourcePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/sampleuser/Downloads/test.txt")
val targetPath = Paths.get("C:/Users/sampleuser/Documents/test.txt")
Files.move(sourcePath, targetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement it later today and then mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I suspect the reason there is no Kotlin `moveTo(...)` method is because it's already so trivial in Java. But if you wanted to, you could wrap up that Java code as a Kotlin extension.

Comment: @Looki Okay I have tried to implement this. However, File("C:/Users/sampleuser/Downloads/test.txt") gives me a NoSuchFileException, however if I copy paste this path in my file explorer, it literally opens the test.txt file. So I am going to try to solve this first.

Comment: Hmm, @Looki any idea why I get that NoSuchFileException, when I am sure that my path is correct?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe try File("C:/Users/sampleuser/Downloads", "test.txt") instead?

Comment: you can also call sourceFile.renameTo(newPath)